# Help understanding a basic complex analysis argument

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading about some basic complex analysis results from the [Supplementary Notes by Joe Schwartz](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/RPECHome.html) in order to understand Weierstrass uniformization. I was wondering if someone can help me understand the step-by-step logic behind the following paragraph (on page 7 of the notes linked above) starting at "If $f(0)\neq 0$, then we are done. If $f(0) = 0$, then...":

[image]

I know and understand all the results described in the notes up until that point, so feel free to quote them without explicit reference in your explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that is being proved here is that 'locally a holomorphic function looks like $z^n$ for some $n$'. This idea is made precise as the following lemma.

$\textbf{Lemma}$ Let $f$ be a function holomorphic in a neighborhood $\Delta $of $0.$ Then $f(z)=z^ng(z)$ for some non-negative integer $n$ and a holomorphic function $g$ such that $g(0)\neq 0$ (and therefore $g(z)\neq 0$ in some neighrhood $\Delta'$ of $0$).

The proof of the above lemma is what you are looking at. And, obviously if $f(0)\neq 0$ then you can take $n=0$ and $g(z)=f(z)$ itself, so you are done. When $f(0)=0,$ the first thing to observe is that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z}=f'(0).$ In particular this measn $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is bounded on $U\setminus\{0\}$ for some neighborhood $U$ of $0.$

After this observation define a new function
$$f_1(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(z)}{z}, & z\neq 0\\
f'(0), & z=0\end{cases}.$$
Clearly $f_1$ is holormophic except possibly at $0.$ But the Riemann removable singularity theorem implies that $f_1$ is holomorphic because $f_1$ is bounded in some neighborhood of $0.$ Obviously, we have $f(z)=zf_1(z).$ Now you repeat the same argument untill you get $f(z)=z^nf_n(z)$ for some $f_n$ such that $f_n(0)\neq 0.$ Only thing you need to be careful is to argue that such an $n$ must exist. But that is easy. If not, it follows that $f^{(k)}=0$ for all $k\ge 0.$ Power series expansion around $0$ therefore vanishes identically.

I should however also add that if you already know that an analytic function is locally represented by a power series, then the proof is very simple. Just let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $f^{(n)}\neq 0.$ Then the power series of $f,$ locally looks like $\sum_{i\ge n}a_nz^n=z^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{n+i}z^i\right).$ Take $g(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{n+i}z^i$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you, very clear!